# I don´t know how i can get the pid of an process by process name

Tags: c, pid, wdk, windows-kernel

I want to get the process id for example of the process "notepad.exe".

I only found threads etc. for how to get process by PID. But I want to get the PID by process name (in this scenario "notepad.exe").
And this with my kernel driver.

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one process with a process image coming from a file `notepad.exe`. You must enumerate all the running processes and retrieve the module name from that. It's described in the MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes

From the list of processes you then extract all the processes with a module name `notepad.exe` and get the list of matching PIDs.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Notepad was just an example, i know that the process which i want can only be runned one time.

Comment: @NachoModding: That doesn't change the fact that from the perspective of the OS in general there's no strictly bijective mapping between module name and PID. And because it's in general not bijective there simply isn't an incentive to have a "GetSinglePIDByModuleName" API. Just enumerate the processes and compare by module name as you'd do for the generalized PID→name surjective mapping and take the (single) first element of the resulting list. Or better, perform a sanity check that you actually get a list with only one entry; and if that check fails assume that your system is in a bad state.

Comment: @NachoModding in kernel driver need use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation` instead `EnumProcesses`. but ofcouse usual use name not the best choice - need ask - for what you this process and search based on something another